# How do the positionAndYawCtrl () and flightCtrl () commands in OSDK affect travel speed?

Tags: c++, dji-sdk

We use STM32,A3 and OSDK. In what range we can set float32_t DJI :: OSDK :: Control :: CtrlData :: x in the command flightCtrl () and x in the command positionAndYawCtrl (), and how this values affect the speed of movement? How to use them correctly?Can I use these commands  and  velocityAndYawRateCtrl() when flying without GPS?